# Installing Numpy locally

Tags: python, numpy, installation

I have an account in a remote computer without root permissions and I needed to install a local version of Python (the remote computer has a version of Python that is incompatible with some codes I have), Numpy and Scipy there. I've been trying to install numpy locally since yesterday, with no success.

I successfully installed a local version of Python (2.7.3) in /home/myusername/.local/, so I access to this version of Python by doing `/home/myusername/.local/bin/python`. I tried two ways of installing Numpy:

1. I downloaded the lastest stable version of Numpy from the official webpage, unpacked it, got into the unpacked folder and did: `/home/myusername/.local/bin/python setup.py install --prefix=/home/myusername/.local`. However, I get the following error, which is followed by a series of other errors (deriving from this one):

   ```
   gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/blasdot/_dotblas.o
   -L/usr/local/lib -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -lptf77blas -lptcblas -latlas 
   -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/_dotblas.so
   /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libptcblas.a(cblas_dptgemm.o): relocation 
   R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared 
   object; recompile with -fPIC
   ```

   Not really knowing what this meant (except that the error apparently has to do with the LAPACK library), I just did the same command as above, but now putting LDFLAGS='-fPIC', as suggested by the error i.e., I did 
   `LDFLAGS="-fPIC" /home/myusername/.local/bin/python setup.py install --prefix=/home/myusername/.local`. 
   However, I got the same error (except that the prefix -fPIC was addeded after the gcc command above).
2. I tried installing it using pip, i.e., doing `/home/myusername/.local/bin/pip install numpy` /after successfully instaling pip in my local path). However, I get the exact same error.

I searched on the web, but none of the errors seemed to be similar to mine. My first guess is that this has to do with some piece of code that needs root permissions to be executed, or maybe with some problem with the version of the LAPACK libraries.

Help, anyone?

Comment: I didn't know of superuser.com! I'll also post the question there, thanks for the suggestion (however, I still wonder...why my question doesn't fit here?).

Comment: -fPIC is a compiling option, not a linking option, so adding it to LDFLAGS will not do anything. You should try adding it to the compiler flags.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! However, even using CFLAGS="-fPIC" raises the same error...

Comment: Are you sure that everything is being recompiled with the new flags? Because the source files haven't changed, it's possible that setup.py is going straight to the linking stage. Make sure you delete the "build" directory before recompiling.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I removed the build directory before I compiled the code with CFLAGS='-fPIC'.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the library has some dependencies that were not compiled with -fPIC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you that your ATLAS library has not been built with the `-fPIC` flag. That means it cannot be linked into a shared library like Python extension modules. You need to rebuild ATLAS with the `-fPIC` flag. The ATLAS documentation describes how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of a pain to build from source.  Is it possible to avoid doing that?

If we assume that you are trying to install on an x86 computer (Intel, AMD, whatever), can you just install Python on another x86 computer where you *do* have root, then make a tar archive of the Python installation, copy the tar to the other computer, and unpack the tar archive?

The problem with the above is that the pre-built Python might have hard-coded paths for where to look for libraries: it might need the libraries to be in `/usr/share` or whatever.  It would be a bit of a hack, but you might be able to make a `chroot` jail and get Python to run.

You might also want to take a look at Enthought Python Distribution (EPD).  I believe the EPD installer simply asks you where you want EPD installed, and installs it there.

http://www.enthought.com/products/epdgetstart.php?platform=linux

There is a free version of EPD.  If you want 64-bit you would have to pay for EPD, but if 32-bit will work for you, EPD Free might be all you need.

http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php

P.S. The Enthought web site seems to be rejecting any URL that doesn't start with `www.`!  This means that some Google search links don't work unless you edit them to insert the `www.` at the beginning.  I'm sure they will fix this soon.

Comment: Yeah, in fact, I think that's the problem: the code is trying to use libraries from /usr/bin/ld. However, I really need a local installation; just copying one already compiled seems unsafe to me.

Comment: I think you can trust Enthought not to put Trojan Horse attacks or other bad things into their build of Python.  But if you really prefer to build it, I hope it works out for you.  Hmmm.  Maybe you should try building from software on a machine where you have root, then make a tar archive of your build and transfer it?  At least this would give you control over which Fortran compiler was used for the build and that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into EasyBuild for building your local Python version with numpy and scipy enabled, see http://hpcugent.github.com/easybuild/.

It basically takes all the nasty stuff away from you, you just need to configure it a little bit (specify where you want the software to end up, for exaple), and then you can build Python with the packages of your choice with a single command.